# What's the most important thing to look at in the datasheet when replacing a transistor with another one?

Tags: transistors, bjt

I'm trying to replace a transistor but I don't know if the transistor that I'm trying to replace is going to work. Can someone help me determine which parameters to look for before replacing?

Comment: Package, pins, and pin spacing, otherwise it won't fit. Polarity and type (jfet vs mosfet vs bjt), otherwise it won't work. The rest are details.

Comment: Look at the specs that relate to the application where you're using it and how it's used in your circuit.

Comment: Electrical characteristics such as operating voltage, reverse leakage current, the maximum collector current limit, current gain (beta) and if you are using it for switching applications, its rise time, fall time. These are very basic parameters that need to be considered and depends on the application more parameters should be included.

Comment: This question and the answers show a relevant example of what happens when a poor relacement is used : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/366463/152903

Comment: This is application dependent, explain what the application is.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is much like what you see in comments, but I thought I would give it some order:

1. Exact package type, Pin-outs and pin spacing. Mandatory.
2. Transistor type. JFET, MOSFET or BJT. Mandatory.
3. Transistor polarity. PNP/NPN or N-channel or P-channel. Mandatory.
4. Operating voltage (max), and maximum continuous current. Mandatory. Note that a small increase in maximum voltage and/or current rating is ok, as long as other parameters are close to the original part.
5. DC gain (hFE or beta). Some transistors are designed with a very high gain. Mandatory.
6. Gain bandwidth. Is it for DC power, audio, RF low band, RF UHF band or higher. Mandatory.

There are more details in good datasheets but become more esoteric unless it is pointed out in a schematic or application notes. The gate resistor for a MOSFET for example. Don't buy a beefy MOSFET to replace one that had a latent failure. Oversize the current rating by a small amount if at all.

A much higher-current MOSFET may fit into your circuit but it will have a much higher gate capacitance, so its driver may heat up and the circuit is not efficient anymore. The same goes for NPN or PNP power transistors in a TO-126 package or larger. Pay attention to the DC gain. Some may have a gain of 100 while older transistors may have a gain of 10.

When dealing with special transistors for RF or JFET or MOSFET types, then attention to fine details are very important. Base or gate capacitance and FET idle current become very important.

Yes, lots of parameters to look into, but for generic stuff like DC power supplies and basic audio the first 6 lines count the most. For RF or switching power supplies look at *ALL* the details.

Do **NOT** buy transistors with no datasheet! Note that buying up lots of older outdated transistors is not always a good idea. Beware of parts brokers who do this for a living.

Comment: Can you add under 4 that you are allowed to increase the voltage and current rating. You don't need an exact match.

Comment: Sure thing, but why small? I would not heasitate to replace a 200 V MOSFET with a 600 V one if the Rdson and Ciss was similar. You will be hard pressed to find an application where the avalanche breakdown voltage of the transistor is an inegral part of the circuit. Some obscure self-resetting forward converter from the 1970s perhaps.

Comment: @winny. I would agree with that, but it takes an experienced technician or engineer to know those details. I did not want to go into a lot of 'gray' areas and confuse others lacking a deep knowledge base about transistors.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the steps that the designer took when choosing the original transistor. So, when you choose a component for a design, you should consider: -

- The desired circuit functionality and
- The desired circuit performance and
- The data sheets of candidate components

When you replace that component with another, you should consider exactly the same: -

- The desired circuit functionality and
- The desired circuit performance and
- The data sheets of candidate component

And, with no circuit to study, it means no clear understanding of: -

- The desired circuit functionality and
- The desired circuit performance

And no clear idea of what component can be chosen