# Can I use 13003 transistor in place of 2n2222?

Tags: transistors, datasheet, npn, wireless-charging

I am working on a project which requires a npn 2n2222a transistor as recommandation. But as of now the transistor is not available to me.

Alternatively I have transistor 13003 and c945 available as of now. 
I have read both datasheets on internet. But am not experienced on reading datasheets, so was unable to make a conclusion.
I have seen that 13003 is a high voltage high collector current fast switching transistor.

But in my circuit my operation voltage probably be within 1.5 v to 10v range. So can I use 13003 in place of 2n2222a?
Alternatively I also have c945 npn transistors available? Are such also be useful in place of 2222?

Datasheets for these three NPNs:

- [13003](https://alltransistors.com/transistor.php?transistor=59514)
- [2n2222](http://www.alldatasheet.com/view.jsp?Searchword=2n2222%20datasheet&gclid=Cj0KCQjw1MXpBRDjARIsAHtdN-3yVuqct6AOUYlfB6agG4IpgNy2O8NcH7GT4Nn4SHhV-CW2bMeTVIQaAoBlEALw_wcB)
- [C945](http://www.alldatasheet.com/view.jsp?Searchword=C945&gclid=Cj0KCQjw1MXpBRDjARIsAHtdN-2F-43X7oe4bFLak1uwsKh-zortHDaFPL1UahkIzlUkNfRKjePZa5QaApN-EALw_wcB)

Comment: Like any question of the type "can A be replaced by B?" the answer is: *We can't tell you without you telling us the exact operational point and purpose of A.*

Comment: The most important thing is the target circuit and how much that circuit might utilize any one particular parameter in the data sheet. If tyre A looks like tyre B could you assume tyre B would fit a car that took tyre A? See [my answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/366507/whats-the-most-important-thing-to-look-on-datasheet-when-replacing-a-transistor) here.

Comment: The role of the transistor in my circuit is to convert DC current  to high frequency AC signal

Comment: _"The role of the transistor in my circuit is to convert DC current to high frequency AC signal"_ Wow! Can you be any broader than that? VTC.

Answer (score 1):

A 13003 (probably a clone of the venerable [MJE13003](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MJE13003-D.PDF), originally a Motorola part) is a high voltage NPN power transistor so has relatively low beta, rather low ft and other significant differences from a jellybean 2N2222.

While we can't really be sure it will or won't work without a lot of analysis (of information that you have not provided) you would be much better off just getting a jellybean NPN from somewhere, even a toy. An 8050, for example, from any Chinese-made gadget would be a better fit. Or buy a few 2N3904 or 2N4401 or BC547 or 2SC1815 for general purpose use.

Assuming the C945 is a 2SC945, it's closer to a 2N2222 and will probably work in many non-critical circuits. Check the pinout both with a real datasheet and with a meter, especially if it's from some dubious source, part number and pinouts are treated a bit cavalierly in some circles.