# Replace IRF7101 with IRF7301 power mosfets

Tags: power, mosfet, replacement

I need to replace a burnt IRF7101
[(datasheet link)](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7101pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355f0e12b1ac2) power MOSFET. Is IRF7301 [(datasheet link)](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7301pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355f1b66c1af8) a good equivalent replacement component? I cannot find the old one in any local store and I need it fixed as soon as possible.
Thanks!

Comment: [Advice about comparing devices without knowledge of the target circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/366507/whats-the-most-important-thing-to-look-on-datasheet-when-replacing-a-transistor)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the IRF7301 is either a more expensive/higher performance drop in for the IRF7101, or a newer upgraded version of it. Either way it basically does the same thing better, and if you have it on hand it'd be a great drop in replacement.

Comment: it's a lower RdsOn identical next generation (5), same cost.