# Replacement of a MOSFET alternative

Tags: mosfet, component-selection

This is the MOSFET part that I'm using in the current design - [LP0701](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/LP0701-P-Channel-Enhancement-Mode-Lateral-MOSFET-Data-Sheet-20005447A.pdf)

Can the [NVJS4151P](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nvjs4151p-d.pdf) be the right alternative for the LP0701? I am not sure as some parameters do not match.

My requirements :

- 500 mA (continuous current)
- 3.3V or 2.5V (source – input voltage)
- 1.2V (drain – output voltage)
- VGS in the range of:
- (–1.2V to –1.5V) @ 500 mA for 3.3V source voltage
- (–1.0V to –1.1V) @ 500 mA for 2.5V source voltage

Would the new part suit?

Comment: You need to show the circuit to properly determine whether the new MOSFET can replace the old MOSFET with the same or better performance. Alternatively, simulate the circuit using the old and new devices to figure this out more exactly.

Comment: Is it possible to tell whether the new part matches or fits my requirements?

Comment: Only by analysing how it performs in the target circuit. You can't do this confidently based on data sheet comparisons.

Comment: This is like saying "Two silver cars, two-door, red pinstripe, black tires. Are they the same?" Depends on if you are driving them on a dirt road, or a racetrack.  P.S. one was a Hummer, the other was a Porsche.

Comment: [More detail in an answer I gave](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/366542/20218)